# Sich richtig für ein Präsent bedanken

Tags: phrase, politeness

Ich habe gestern ein Präsent als Dank für eine Dienstleistung von einer Bekannten bekommen, wusste aber nicht, wie ich zum Ausdruck bringen kann, dass ich zwar für das Präsent dankbar bin, ich jedoch die Dienstleistung für sie auch so gerne getan habe, dass das Präsent nicht nötig gewesen ist. Wie kann man dies richtig ausdrücken, ohne ein Missverständnis zu verursachen? Gibt es dafür vielleicht übliche Redewendungen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ganz einfach:

> Das wäre doch/doch aber/aber nicht nötig gewesen!

Betont wird **nicht nötig**. Das *doch/doch aber/aber* ist wichtig, weil es ausdrückt, dass das Geschenk angenehm ist.

> Das wäre nicht nötig gewesen.

kann man mal im Hausflur sagen, völlig ohne Modalpartikel kann es aber sogar als unerwünschte Gefälligkeit verstanden werden. Ein ganz grober Schnitzer ist das hingegen das Weglassen des Konjunktivs:

> Das ist nicht nötig gewesen.
>
> Das war nicht nötig.

sind gefährlich nahe an der Missbilligung des Geschenks. Diese beiden Sätze sagt man, wenn einem ein Missgeschick passiert. Ähnlich, wenn man stattdessen *nicht müssen* verwendet, was im ersten Gedanken ja sogar naheliegt:

> Das musste nicht sein.

drückt aus, dass jemand sich in den Augen des Sprechers falsch verhalten hat, und

> Das musste doch/doch aber/aber nicht sein.

macht die Sache sogar schlimmer, denn es bedeutet, dass es leicht ersichtliche Alternativen gab.

Comment: Antwort gefällt mir, vor allem das Eingehen auf die diversen Modalpartikel und den Konjunktiv.  Aber das erste Beispiel ist nicht eindeutig, da komt u.U. zweimal "aber" drin vor, das musst du noch nachbessern

Comment: Das soll als *doch* oder *aber* oder *doch aber* gelesen werden.

Comment: Ich glaube einfach, das "feste aber" ist zu viel.

Comment: Es ist ja kein festes *aber*. Wäre es das, ergäbe sich die Liste *doch/aber/doch* mit einer Doppelung. Man kann das eigentlich nur absichtlich falsch verstehen.

Comment: Ich hab's tatsächlich auf Anhieb nicht verstanden, dass du nicht  (doch)/(aber)/(doch) aber sondern (doch)/(aber)/(aber doch) meinst. Nimm' doch einfach das (doch aber) in die Mitte, dann kann sowas nicht passieren.

Comment: Mal gucken, wer das nun als *doch/doch*, *aber/aber* liest.

Comment: Janka, vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort! Die Beispiele, wie man es nicht machen sollte, sind besonders hilfreich - genau solche Missverständnisse wollte ich beim mich Bedanken vermeiden :)

Comment: Ich würde das "Das wäre doch/aber aber/doch nicht nötig gewesen!". So steht vorne doch oder doch und hinten aber oder aber - das ist völlig gaga.

Comment: @Janka Ich! Erst dank der Kommentare bin ich dahinter gekommen.

Comment: Auf Bairisch geht auch »Das hätte es aber nicht gebraucht« … klingt aber auf Hochdeutsch sch…

Answer (score 1):

Die schon genannte Standard-Floskel »Das wäre doch nicht nötig gewesen!« tritt allein auf oder auch eingeleitet, mit mehr oder weniger gespieltem Entsetzen unter der Überschrift »wohin soll das noch führen«.

> Aber Frau Schlüter, das wäre doch nicht nötig gewesen!
>
> Aber ich bitte Sie, das wäre doch nicht nötig gewesen!
>
> Aber Frau Schlüter, Sie haben sich in Unkosten gestürzt, das wäre doch
> nicht nötig gewesen!

Im Übrigen wird auch die Wortgruppe »ja nun wirklich« eingesetzt.

> - das hätte ja nun wirklich nicht sein müssen
> - das wäre ja nun wirklich nicht nötig gewesen